# Looping ASCII Values Between 32 to 126 And Add Values To Them

Tags: c, loops, c-strings

I am trying to make program that **loops ASCII value between 32 to 126** and then **add the value of each character of string by 10**given by user and print it on screen. Example:- If user enter the string '"xyz", the **output is '130 131 132' instead of this the output should be like '35 36 37'**.Here is my code below

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
    {
       char str[100];
       int i=0;
       printf("Enter a string: ");
       fgets(str,100,stdin); 
     str[strcspn(str,"\n")]='\0';
       printf("String is: %s\n",str);
     printf("\nASCII value in Decimal is: ");
       while(str[i]!='\0')
        {
             printf("%d ",str[i]);
         i++;
         }
          printf("\n\nAfter adding '10',ASCII value changes to: ");
        for(i = 0; i < str[i]; i++) 
        {
        printf("%d ",str[i] += 10); 
        }
    getch();
}
```

I don't know about arrays and recursion because they were not in my course at college, so I don't know if this thing can be done with any of them.

Comment: You *are* using arrays...

Comment: Do you want to rotate the characters in the range 32 to 126 as in ROT47? Then you must bring the character to a zero-based range and use modulo ariithmetic: `c = 32 + (c - 32 + shift) % (127 - 32)`. (Although ROT47 leaves the space intact and starts shifting from ASCII 33.)

Comment: Your loop end control in `for(i = 0; i < str[i]; i++) ` should be `for(i = 0; str[i]; i++) `

Comment: yes @M Oehm i want to rotate it just like in ROT47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you "rotate" characters as in a Caesar shift or as in ROT47, you must account for shifting outside the range. You can do that by subtracting the width of the range after overflow:

```
s[i] = s[i] + shift;
if (s[i] >= 127) s[i] -= (127 - 33);
```

or with modulo arithmetic on the zero-based index within the valid range.:

```
s[i] = 33 + (s[i] - 33 + shift) % (126 - 33);
```

Note that these methods will only work when the shift is positive. You could account for a negative shift by making the shift the range width minus the shift. You should also ensure that you don't touch the characters outside the valid range.

Here's a small program that implements functions to rotate the ASCII range and to print the ASCII values:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define LO 33        // inclusive lower bound of ASCII shift region
#define HI 127       // exclusive upper bound of ASCII shift region

void asciirot(char *s, int shift)
{
    while (shift < 0) shift += (HI - LO);

    for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
        if (LO <= s[i] && s[i] < HI) {
            s[i] = LO + (s[i] - LO + shift) % (HI - LO);
        }
    }
}

void putascii(const char *s)
{
    printf("{");

    for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
        if (i) printf(", ");
        printf("%d", s[i]);
    }

    puts("}");        
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "The quick brown fox jumps over 1,206 lazy dogs!";

    puts(str);

    asciirot(str, 10);
    puts(str);
    putascii(str);

    asciirot(str, -10);
    puts(str);
    putascii(str);

    return 0;
}
```